# Features extraction in Real-time prediction in sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, lambda, amazon-sagemaker, fraud-prevention

i want to deploy a real time prediction machine learning model for fraud detection using sagemaker.

i used sagemaker jupyter instance to:

```
-load my training data from s3 contains transactions
-preprocessing data and features engineering (i use category_encoders to encode the categorical value)
-training the model and configure the endpoint
```

For the inference step , i used a lambda function which  invoke my endpoint to get the prediction for each real time transaction.

```
should i calculte again all the features for this real time transactions in lambda function ?

for the features when i use category_encoders with fit_transform() function to transform my categorical feature to numerical one, what should I do because the result will not be the same as training set?

is there another method not to redo the calculation of the features in the inference step?
```

Comment: Did you get to get more insights on this? I'm trying to do the same thing. I've read you can build an 'inferencing pipeline' which can include pre-processing (feature engineering), inferencing and post-processing in one same endpoint. This inferencing pipeline can be hit from lambda as well.

Answer (score 0):

> should i calculate again all the features for this real time transaction in lambda function?

Yes, when inference a trained model (or predict on real-time data), you should pass *exactly the same features list* that you use for the training model. If you calculate some features while training (e.g. `part of the day` from `timestamp`) you should also calculate these features while inferencing.

> for the features when i use category_encoders with fit_transform() function to transform my categorical feature to numerical one, what should I do because the result will not be the same as training set?

You should *store all transformations* that you use for training model: numeric `scalers`, categorical `encoders`, etc.

For python it looks like this:

```py
import joblib # for dump fitted transformers
import category_encoders as ce

# 1. while training model
# fit encoder on historical data
encoder = ce.OneHotEncoder(cols=[...])
encoder.fit(X, y)
# and dump it
joblib.dump(encoder, 'filename.joblib') 

# 2. while inference a trained model
# load fitted encoder
encoder = joblib.load('filename.joblib')
# and apply transformation to new data
encoder.transform(X_new)
```